# Cosine similarities to DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, cosine-similarity

I have the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def get_tf_idf_query_similarity(documents, query):
    allDocs = []
    for document in documents:
        allDocs.append(nlp.clean_tf_idf_text(document))
    docTFIDF = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(allDocs)
    queryTFIDF = TfidfVectorizer().fit(allDocs)
    queryTFIDF = queryTFIDF.transform([query])

    cosineSimilarities = cosine_similarity(queryTFIDF, docTFIDF).flatten()
    return cosineSimilarities
```

I need to convert those similarities to `DataFrame` like this:

[image]

`allDocs` represents the different documents and `query` is the same new document that is evaluated against every document in `allDocs`.
How could I perform this operation?
Thanks in advance